# Get K2 itemID in category listing

Tags: k2, rsform, itemid

I have a form created with **RSForm Pro** and I am loading this form in some K2 items with the RSForm Content Plugin.

**I want to get the title of k2 item that form submitted from it**. 
in k2 item view I solve this problem with this code.

```
$K2Itemid = JRequest::getInt('id');$db = JFactory::getDBO();$db->setQuery("SELECT title FROM #__k2_items WHERE id = ".$K2Itemid );$K2Catid = $db->loadResult(); return $K2Catid;
```

but **what is solution in category blog view of k2 items?**

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a hidden field in RS Form and in its default value field insert a code as below:

```
//<code>
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
return ($jinput->get('id', 'No K2 Item', 'INT'));
//</code>
```

Your hidden field will be sending the K2 Item's id, assuming you are only using it inside K2 items, with each submission.